# How to place window on second screen?

Tags: notebooks, options, mac-os-x, palettes

I am trying to open a window on a second screen (a thunderbolt display attached to a macbook pro) that is the full size of the second screen. Here is the command I use:

```
ThunderboltDimensions = {2560, 1440};
window = CreatePalette[{}, WindowSize -> ThunderboltDimensions, 
  WindowTitle -> None, WindowMargins -> {{1440, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}]
```

This opens a window that looks correct, except that the top edge is about half way down the display. In fact, no changes to the second part of the `WindowMargins` value seem to have any effect.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug? Is there a simpler way to specify a second screen? And why does 1440 work for the left edge (Mac Pro display width is 2880)?